# Writing functional tests for Django RESTful API

Tags: django, functional-testing, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to write some functional tests for a REST API written using Django REST Framework. It's not very specific to that framework though, since it's mostly general Django stuff.

This is what I want to do

1. Create a user in the `setUp` method of the test class
2. Request the users token from the API using the test client

**tests.py**

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test.client import Client
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class TokenAuthentication(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create(username='foo', password='password', email="foo@example.com")
        user.save()
        self.c = Client()

    def test_get_auth_token(self):
        user = User.objects.get(username="foo")
        print user # this outputs foo
        print Token.objects.get(user_id = user.pk) # this outputs a normal looking token
        response = self.c.post("/api-token-auth/", {'username': 'foo', 'password': 'password'})
        print response.status_code # this outputs 400
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, "User couldn't log in")
```

When I run the test it returns status 400 rather than 200, so the user wasn't authenticated. If I enter the credentials of a user already in the database it passes though. So I assume records created in the test class are only accessible within it's own methods, which is probably because it's designed for unit testing. But I use data from the database to perform the test it will fail if the data changes.

How should a functional test like this, where data needs to be created before running the test, be performed in Django?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are creating the user incorrectly. `User.objects.create` sets the password in plain-text rather than through the hashing mechanism. You should instead be using [`User.objects.create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#creating-users) which will properly set the password so that you can authenticate with the username and password.